# What are the best translations of "Take it as it goes" and "go forward in the light/ Ever forward in the light"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, latin-to-english-translation

For take it as it goes I have this so far "Ut áuferant eam abscedit" or " Accipiant illam" althought I don't know how accurate either is is.

For go forward in the light I have "procedure ad lucem" or "Procedat lux."

Are there any other translations that would be better? and how valid are my current translations?

Thank you :)

Clarification: Quietly accept what ever happens in stride. and a personal spiritual path with the spiritual light.  As an exhortation to one person rather than multiple.

I really appreciate this!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you elaborate on the intended meaning? Are the two translations your own? They seem so but I'm not sure. The checklist [in this meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/483/79) is quite useful making a translation question clearer. (Registering your account gives you better access to your post when you want to edit it or react to answers.)

Answer (score 2):

Your translations are all a little off:

*Ut áuferant eam abscedit* means "he/she/it departed that they might take her away"

*Accipiant illam* means "let them receive her"

*procedure ad lucem* is gibberish; *procedere ad lucem* means "to advance towards the light"

*Procedat lux* means "let the light go forth"

To give a better translation, we would need some supplementary information on what ideas you want to express by those phrases.

---

One way to say "take it as it goes" could be **accidentias accipe** – "accept chance events", or **accipe fortunam** – "accept your luck".

For "ever forward in the light" you could quite literally say **semper prorsum in luce**.

Comment: I want to express a command from one to another. "Go forward in the light." "Take it as it goes," I am new to semantics and have no general understanding of latin. What information can I provide to help? Thank you for your time

Comment: @CameronGriffith well, but what does "take it as it goes" mean in the intended context? Does it mean something more like "quietly accept whatever happens" or more like "if life hands you lemons, make lemonade"? And what does "light" refer to – physical light? the light of knowledge? spiritual light? And "forward" in which sense? physically marching on? the inexorable march of progress? a personal spiritual path? Those differences in intended meaning could affect how best to translate a phrase into another language.

Comment: Quietly accept what ever happens in stride.   and a personal spiritual path with the spiritual light. I really appreciate this

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give the imperative form—a command—but if you wanted something that works more as an exhortation, you could try the subjunctive.

For the second sentence, try: *Excedas in lucem* ("go forth into the light")

This is actually historically attested, as Livy (in a periocha) has the following sentence:

> vir sapiens laetus ex his tenebris in lucem illam excesserit.
> the wise man will go forth from these shadows into that light.

The subjunctive of *accipe* is *accipias*, and *fatum* is a fine enough choice.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of attempts of translation by me. I am assuming that these are self-inspiring words, so the translation will be giving orders to a singular person:

"Accipe datum."

*Datum* means 'thing (which has been) given.'

*Accipe* means 'accept.'

One could probably exchange the -um ending on *datum* for -a, if they wanted to be specific about the plurality of things. I chose the singular because I prefer the -um sound.

---

"Luce fungere in perpetua."

*Luce* is in the ablative, here meaning with light.

*Fungere* is a 2nd person imperative, meaning perform/execute/discharge (duty)/be engaged in.

*In perpetua* is a set phrase meaning forever/in perpetuity.

Altogether, this phrase means: act with the light in perpetuity.

I could have used plenty of words for do or act, but *fungor* feels like a more formal word, closer associated with doing one's duty compared to *ago* for example.